# Creating a package.json with all devDependencies listed

Tags: json, node.js, terminal, npm, gulp

## Question

I was wondering if when doing `npm init` in the Terminal to create a `package.json` to go along with Gulp if you can have all your `devDependencies` already listed in the file as opposed to having to install each manually or cloning the file from another project?

### devDependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.8.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.4"
  }
```

Comment: do `npm install` that will install all listed dependencies

Comment: @entre I'm looking moreso to create a `package.json` that's not blank by default when I do `npm init` and rather has all the devDependencies already listed in the file without having to npm install each Gulp plugin one by one or cloning the file from a repo

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is some sort of default `package.json`. It can be created when initializing your project. It's described in step 2 of the [Gulp getting started guide](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

This command should be executed after installing Gulp.